# Add Javascript to Direct Link of an Image

Tags: javascript, image, .htaccess, redirect

I'm new at building websites, is there anyway to hide this code in the direct link of an image? IE

```
www.YYY.com/ZZZ.jpg

<script src="http://YYY.com/ZZZ.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Hide what code? Hide in what sense? Can you describe your use-case in a little more detail? It will definitely help you get your question answered.

Comment: If you're asking if you can load a script with an image tag... no, you can't do that.

Comment: Hi robe, Im sorry, like I said I am new, and I know you guys are all extremely smart over hear at this site! ha I guess by hide I mean just add to the page, the direct image url.

Comment: no not an image tag, I want to be able to have a direct image URL with that script above attached so a pop up comes up if you click on the url  to view the image.